# Questions getting repeated

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have made a random quiz through javascript and HTML, the questions are in a JSON file, but when I run the quiz it repeats some of the questions multiple times, how do I make it that no questions are repeated.

```
function renderQuestion(){
let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuestions.length);
runningQuestion = availableQuestions[index];
availableQuestions.pop(index);
let q = questions[runningQuestion];
question.innerHTML = "<p>"+ q.question +"</p>";
qImg.innerHTML = "<img src="+ q.imgSrc +">";
choiceA.innerHTML = q.choiceA;
choiceB.innerHTML = q.choiceB;
choiceC.innerHTML = q.choiceC;
```

}

Comment: you may wanna shuffle array then slice number of questions you need if not all.

Comment: Remove the questions from the array after you picked them. (create a shallow copy of the array first in case your code supports starting a new game without reloading questions.)

Comment: `availableQuestions.pop(index);` should be `availableQuestions.splice(index, 1);`

Comment: Thank you @Rojo that's fixed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to remove an object from an array by using
<s>`pop(index)`</s>.
This is not possible since `pop` will always **remove the last** element in the array (and does not accepts any parameters!).

**Use [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead:**

```
availableQuestions.splice(index, 1);  // Remove 1 element at specific index
```

Answer (score 1):

you could push the "index" into an array, like

```
const usedQuestions = [];
```

And then when u create a new index look through the "usedQuestions" index to not use them again.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.pop` does not accept a parameter, passing the index is not doing anything here. It is simply popping the last element from the array.

Let's say you have question array `qa = [a, b, c, d, e]`.

You generate a random index (`index = 2`) and set running question to that index (`runningQuestion = qa[2]`, => `runningQuestion = 'c'`). You then pop an element and the array becomes `qa = [a, b, c, d]`.

On the next function call, it is still possible to retrieve the question `c`.

I recommend the following approaches

1. Randomize the array, and iterate over them
2. Instead of `pop`, use `splice`